# Round off the number 8.03567 to four significant digits and compute the percentage error.

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, computational-mathematics

I rounded off the number 8.03567 to four significant digits and it'll be 8.036 but, the problem is how can I compute the percentage error because there's not enough data to compute.

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the percentage error be given by the difference between the approximation and the actual number, divided by the actual number?

Formulaically, let $\bar x$ approximate $x$. Then the error as a percent would be given by

$$\frac{|\bar x - x|}{x} \times 100\%$$

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since the percentage error is| experimental value-accepted value|/accepted value*100 the solution would be |8.036-8.03567|  /8.03567*100=0.004106689299%

Comment: Here's [a reference for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you might find useful, which is preferred for writing up and rendering your math text on this site.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thank you so much!